# Laravel Https not redirecting properly

Tags: apache, laravel-5, https

I am trying to move my website (Built with laravel 5.6) from http to https.
I installed the ssl certificates and configured apache properly.

Now if i use the link http://checkup.domain.com it redirects properly to https and shows the requested page. The redirection works as well for all other routes, but the problem is i am receiving 404 errors. Only "/" is showing me a valid response.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

How are you handling your routes in the application? Make sure you force SSL in your Laravel app for the routes if you haven't.

In you **app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php** add a forcescheme in the register function. You could also set it to only run for production (if your production have APP_ENV set to production)

```
public function register()
{
   if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
       $this->app['url']->forceScheme('https');
   }
}
```

Comment: The changes you suggested was unfortunately ineffective.

Comment: What do you mean how am i handling the routes? I rely on Routes/web.php

Comment: Elie, I mean, do you handle the https with a middleware, or a forcedScheme. I'm not sure this is needed for every configuration, but the forcedScheme have solved the problem you explain for me in several Laravel apps. Is the APP_ENV=production in your .env file online?

Comment: I didn't include the if statement in the function. And no i do not use a middleware but the home page works fine.